# GRUB loader won't start in secure boot

Tags: kali-linux, grub2, grub, secure-boot

I have a dual boot setup. I am using Kali Linux and Windows 10. They were working fine until I forgot to shut down my system and Kali went into hibernation. After that PC shutdown-ed because of low power and now I am unable to boot into GRUB loader without disabling secure boot. How can I fix it? Also, I saw a message that CMOS has been reset.

Comment: Very likely when you installed the system, linux installed secure boot keys for linux in your cmos settings.  These may have been lost by the CMOS reset.  Reinstalling grub (in ubuntu, this would be `grub-install`) may fix this, but there is also a specific command to manipulate secure boot entries for linux.

Comment: I know that this is most likely the case but I'm not sure how to add the entry back in the secure boot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute

`grub-install --uefi-secure-boot`.

Otherwise your system won't boot with SecureBoot enabled.

Comment: FYI here is what `grub-install --help` says about this option: `install an image usable with UEFI Secure Boot. This option is only available on EFI and if grub-efi-amd64-signed package is installed.`

Answer (score 0):

You can reinstall grub with the following procedure:

- Disable secure boot
- Boot linux
- `grub-install`
- reboot and re-enable secure boot and see if that fixed it

Note that if this process has to enroll keys, you may be given additional instructions to follow to enable enrollment of the key during the boot process.

The ubuntu [secure boot](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot) page may be helpful if the above isn't sufficient.